# How to use OAuth signature_type in Apps Script?

Tags: api, google-apps-script, oauth

I have the following OAuth authentication script in Python that works for the api. I want to convert it to run in Google Apps Script using the `signature_type='query'`. How should I do it?

```
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1

BASE_URL = '...'
CLIENT_KEY = '...'
CLIENT_SECRET = '...'

def get_oauth_query():
    """ Get OAuth Query """
 
    queryoauth = OAuth1(CLIENT_KEY, CLIENT_SECRET, signature_type="query")
    return queryoauth

url = BASE_URL + '/user/v2/credentials/'
queryoauth = OAuth1(CLIENT_KEY, CLIENT_SECRET, signature_type="query")
request = requests.get(url, auth=get_oauth_query())
content = request.json()
credentialId = content[0]["id"]
 
print(credentialId)
```

P.S.: I cannot use Library service on the work laptop, but I can copy the following [OAuth script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth1/blob/main/dist/OAuth1.gs) into my project.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought that in the case of `signature_type="query"`, the values are used as the query parameter. From your question, when you want to use [OAuth1 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth1), how about converting your Python script as follows?

**In this sample script, it supposes that [OAuth1 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth1) is used. Please be careful about this.**

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const BASE_URL = "...";
  const CLIENT_KEY = "...";
  const CLIENT_SECRET = "...";

  const service = OAuth1.createService("sample")
    .setConsumerKey(CLIENT_KEY)
    .setConsumerSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
    .setParamLocation("uri-query")
    .setAccessToken("", "");
  const url = BASE_URL + "/user/v2/credentials/";
  const response = service.fetch(url);

  // console.log(response.getContentText()); // You can see the raw response value using this line.

  const content = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  const credentialId = content[0]["id"];
  console.log(credentialId);
}
```

- From `signature_type="query"` of your Python script, `setParamLocation("uri-query")` is used.
- I think that this request is the same as your showing Python script. But, if an error occurs, please confirm your values of `BASE_URL`, `CLIENT_KEY`, and `CLIENT_SECRET`, again.

#### Reference:

- [OAuth1 for Apps Script](https://github.com/googleworkspace/apps-script-oauth1)